# How to remove numbers from string using PySpark's RegexTokenizer?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to remove numbers with 5 or more digits from a DataFrame column using PySpark's RegexTokenizer. I was able to extract these numbers using the codes below but does anyone know how I can remove them instead?

My code:

```
regexTokenizer = RegexTokenizer(inputCol="description", outputCol="tokenized_description", gaps=False,pattern="[0-9]{5,}")
```

If the string is "123abc 122323232", I want it to remove 122323232 and becomes "123abc"

Answer (score 0):

`RegexTokenizer` breaks apart the string into tokens using the regex pattern as delimiter.

You can join the words in the array after this fact by applying `pyspark.sql.functions.array_join` function on transformed column.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_join
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
            .builder\
            .appName("Pattern Replacement Example")\
            .getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([('123abc 122323232',)],['pattern'])
regexTokenizer = RegexTokenizer(inputCol="pattern", outputCol="words", pattern="[0-9]{5,}")
df_words = regexTokenizer.transform(df)

df_pattern_removed = df_words.select(array_join("words", '').alias("pattern_removed"), "pattern", "words").show(truncate=False)

print(df_pattern_removed.show(truncate=False))
```

I suggest using Spark SQL where possible, particularly the `pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace` function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
            .builder\
            .appName("Pattern Replacement Example")\
            .getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([('123abc 122323232',)],['pattern'])

df_pattern_removed = df.select(
    regexp_replace('pattern', r'[0-9]{5,}', '').alias('pattern_replaced'), 
    "pattern"
)

print(df_pattern_removed.show(truncate=False))
```

Note that this matches a string having characters from `0-9` thrice followed by `a-z` thrice.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! However, I need to include this function into the RegexTokenizer as I need to write this tokenizer into a disk. Is there anyway I can modify the pattern in RegexTokenizer to have the same result as using regexp_replace?